# Internet connection failure

Tags: ssh, web-interface

I have bought a Raspberry Pi B and have set up the IP address configuration so that it would directly be connected to the Internet.

But the problem is, my Raspberry Pi doesn't seem to work when connected to the Internet.

After connecting to the Internet, I try to remote login through [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) or from terminal and ssh in Ubuntu, but both ways fail to establish a connection. I even 'ping' it, but I receive none back.

But weirdly, when I directly connect the Raspberry Pi and my laptop with a LAN cable, it does work.

Furthermore, at first the Internet connection did work, but while remote login and executing 'sudo apt-get update', I accidently closed the terminal that was connected to the Raspberry Pi.

After this, the Internet connection didn't work.... could I have accidently disrupted the Raspberry Pi itself that it won't work with the Internet connection?

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What do you mean by `when connected to the internet`? What is it actually connected to? What is the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @Milliways `when connected to the internet` means when I plug the ethernet LAN to the RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you can connect to the RPi from the laptop via direct Ethernet connection indicates that the sshd process is running on the RPi and most likely working correctly. One potential problem is that the RPi address that you were using on the local network is not known when coming from the internet but you would most likely have received an error message saying something about an unknown host or address. Another potential problem is that your firewall may be blocking inbound ICMP traffic and inbound TCP traffic for port 22 used by ssh. I believe most firewalls allow this traffic on your local network but usually do not allow traffic like this past the firewall.